# OutOfMemory Exception for EPPlus when running in Azure

Tags: .net, azure, out-of-memory, azure-web-app-service, epplus

I'm trying to process a large XLSX file using EPPlus version 4.5.3.2.

Everything runs fine on my local machine, but in Azure I get the following exception:

```
Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
at OfficeOpenXml.Packaging.ZipPackage..ctor(Stream stream)
at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.ConstructNewFile(String password)
at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage..ctor(FileInfo newFile)
```

At the following line in code:

```
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
```

The XLSX file I'm trying to open is 190MB in size, and if I open that file using 7-Zip, I can see that the contents unzipped are around 1.7GB, so that is what I would expect the memory footprint to be like.

As mentioned above, when I run this locally in Visual Studio, inside a ASP.NET Core 2 application in IIS Express everything works out fine.

The exception above is from my App service in Azure.

The App service runs as an S3 instance that has 7GB of memory, so that should be enough.

I also tried going into **Configuration > General settings** and changing Platform to 64-bit so that I would not be limited by the 2GB per process for a 32-bit system, but the same problem occurs now.

Any ideas here how I can get this to work in Azure?

Comment: Did You resolve this problem?